# C# Console app, Can't keep program running in while loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, console-application

I am trying to change Console color when user press certain keys, but I doing something wrong in while loop. try break and return, but both does not work for me. I still new to coding.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true )
        {Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
            Console.ReadLine();

            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.R)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                //Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
               break;
            }

            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.G)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
                //break;
            }

            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.B)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Clear();
               Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
                //return;
            }

            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
              // break;
            }

            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.C)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.Clear();
               Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
               // break;
            }

            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.M)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
              //  break;
            }

            else {
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't press Key R,G,B,D,C,M.");
              //Console.ReadLine();
               // return;
            }
         // Console.ReadLine(); 

        }      
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Define "does not work".  What *does* it do?  What are you *expecting* it to do?

Comment: You're doing a readline within every iteration. Are you sure you're not putting in a key for  that readline?

Comment: If you want to have this loop running after you've entered the key, then you **have to** use `continue` instead of `return` or `break` because those keywords will **leave** the loop. `continue`, on the other hand, will start new iteration.

Comment: +1 to kostbone... this is clearly a homework question and he gave just enough to keep Vishal on track and let him figure the rest out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was not working because: you were first expecting the user to input a line and then a key.

Second: if the user pressed r the while loop would break.

You should read the key before you start checking the user input because on every `if` you were expecting a new key press.

```
   while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");

                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.R)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.G)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.M)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You didn't press Key R,G,B,D,C,M.");
                }

            };
```

Comment: Code from @Zippy works, I was trying to change console color by just pressing keys and stay in loop, so it does not exit application. Thanks everyone guys.

Answer (score 2):

According to what you want to implement

> change Console color when user press certain keys

`Console.ReadLine` on every iteration is redundant.

Exiting while loop on pressing `R` key is also unexpected behaviour.

Try following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  while (true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color. Press E to Exit");
    switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
    {
      case ConsoleKey.R:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.G:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.B:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Clear();
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.D:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Clear();
        break;

      case ConsoleKey.C:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.Clear();
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.M:
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.E:
        return;
      default:
        Console.WriteLine("You didn't press Key R,G,B,D,C,M.");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press Key R,G,B,D,C,M to change Console Color");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @tchelidze your code also get what I was trying to get.

Comment: @VishalBarot Glad if helped.